# Clone a repository behind a proxy using GitPython

Tags: proxy, gitpython

I'm currently working on a project which uses GitPython to clone repositories.

After reading through the documentation, there is nothing on how to clone a repository that is behind an http proxy.

If I were to use the git command line, I could just set the http.proxy option in the global .gitconfig.

Is there anyway I could do this through GitPython?

Ideally, I would not want to mess with the global .gitconfig. Maybe using git config unset would suffice.

Comment: Do you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

From the GitPython documentation for the clone method it says:

> **kwargs "All remaining keyword arguments are given to the git-clone command"

I used the following and it worked for me

```
from git import Repo

Repo.clone_from(GIT_URL, DESTINATION, config="http.proxy='http://proxy_host:proxy_port'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is that no need to use ''
Example of syntax:

```
Repo.clone_from(GIT_URL, DESTINATION, config="http.proxy=http://proxy_host:proxy_port")
```

Example from my code that works OK:

```
# [PROXY]

proxy_cfg = None

if proxy_list is not None:
    proxy_ip_port = proxy_list[random.randrange(0, len(proxy_list))]
    proxy_cfg = f"http.proxy={proxy_ip_port}"

print(f'\n[debug]: {proxy_cfg}')    

try:
    Repo.clone_from(repo_url, repo_savepath, config=proxy_cfg)
except git.exc.GitError as ex1:
    print(f'\n[EXCEPTION-{self.tot_errs}]: {proc_name}. ErrMsg: {ex1}\n')
except Exception as ex:
    self.tot_errs += 1
    print(f'\n[Error-{self.tot_errs}]: {proc_name}. ErrMsg: {ex}\n')
```